# Javascript diff WikEdDiff: disable blocks entirely and improve comparison

Tags: javascript, diff

I'm trying to use the [WikEdDiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Cacycle/diff) javascript lib to compare strings within my web page, but I'm unable to configure it correctly. Consider this example created with the [online tool](http://cacycle.altervista.org/wikEd-diff-tool.html):

[image: Diff output]

I'm comparing the two strings:

```
- Lorem ipsum 3. Same text 1 and 2.
- Lorem ipsum 969 and 100. Same text must be typed.
```

There are two problems with the result displayed on the image:

1. I want to display only additions and deletions, without blocks. As you can see, even if I **unchecked Show block moves** it still displays a block (#1 in the image). How can I hide that (analyzing the page while hovering over the word "and" actually displays a block CSS code that I do not want because of the hovering).
   [image: "and" block]
2. I don't understand why the "2" is not tied with "1 and 2"; I would expect a **result like this**:

Lorem ipsum <s>3</s> 969 and 100. Same text <s>1 and 2</s> must be typed.
*(spaces added here only to improve reading)*

How do I achieve that? I've tried enabling and disabling repeated diff, reject blocks and so on but without any success. This is the code, but you can see the same issues on the online tool, though.

```js
var wikEdDiffConfig;
if (wikEdDiffConfig === undefined) { wikEdDiffConfig = {}; }
wikEdDiffConfig.fullDiff = true;
wikEdDiffConfig.showBlockMoves = false;

var wikEdDiff = new WikEdDiff();
var diffHtml = wikEdDiff.diff(
  "Lorem ipsum 3. Same text 1 and 2.",
  "Lorem ipsum 969 and 100. Same text must be typed."
);
document.getElementById("compare").innerHTML = diffHtml;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For problem #1 it seems a bug of the script. I've patched like this and it works:

```patch
--- wkdiff.js   Fri Jun 26 00:00:00 2020
+++ wkdiff.original Fri Jun 26 00:00:00 2020
@@ -3767,7 +3767,7 @@
            }
 
            // Add colored right-pointing block start markup
-           else if ( type === '(>' && this.config.showBlockMoves === true) {
+           else if ( type === '(>' ) {
                if ( version !== 'old' ) {
 
                    // Get title
```

Problem #2 is still unsolved and it's probably due to the "and" word that confuses the block search?